# Create an association between one model that has two foreign_keys to another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, foreign-key-relationship, classname

Struggling with this association, I have two models: Figure and Market, a market is where you can trade your toy figure with someone else.

```
Figure class
  figure_id:integer
  name     :string
  image_url:string

Market class
  market_id:integer
  figure_you_want_to_trade_id         :integer #this should be associated with the figure_id
  figure_you_want_from_someone_else_id:integer #this should be associated with the figure_id
```

how do I go about making this association?

I'm thinking:

```
market.rb
  has_many :figure_to_trade, :class_name => Figure, :foreign_key => figure_id
  has_many :figure_you_want, :class_name => Figure, :foreign_key => figure_id

figure.rb
  belongs_to :figure_you_want_to_trade, :class_name => Market
  belongs_to :figure_you_want_from_someone_else, :class_name => Market
```

This is the error I'm receiving when I try to output this: <%= market.figure_to_trade %>

SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: figures.figure_id: SELECT "figures".* FROM "figures"  WHERE "figures"."figure_id" = 1

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out

```
market.rb
    belongs_to :figure_you_want_to_trade, :class_name => Figure
    belongs_to :figure_you_want_from_someone_else, :class_name => Figure

figure.rb
    has_many :figure_to_trade, :class_name => Market, :foreign_key => :figure_you_want_to_trade_id
    has_many :figure_you_want, :class_name => Market, :foreign_key => :figure_you_want_from_someone_else_id
```

Then I can call it by (assuming Figure class has name:string)

```
<% @markets.each do |market| %>
  <%= market.figure_you_want_to_trade.name %>
  <%= market.figure_you_want_from_someone_else.name %>
<% end %>
```